# P5 - bouncing ball from left to right and back

Tags: javascript, loops, processing, p5.js

I am trying to make the ball infinite bounce from the right to the left but I can't get it to work. The code downbelow makes it that the ball will go to the right and back to the left but I can't get it to bounce back again to the right. someone has any ideas how to fix this?

```
var speed = 3;
var ball = {
x: 100,
y: 200,

draw: function() {
    fill('red');
    circle(this.x, this.y, 100);
},
move: function(){
    if(this.x > width){
        speed = -3;
    }
    this.x = this.x + speed;
}
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500);
    background(200, 225, 200);
}

function draw() {
    background(200,225,200);
    ball.draw();
    ball.move();

    }
```

P.S. This is my first post please tell me if I am doing something wrong or need to add anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to invert the direction of movement (`speed *= -1`), if the ball either hits the right (`this.x > width`) or hits the left (`this.x < 0`):

```js
let radius = 50;
if (this.x > width-radius  || this.x < radius ) {
    speed *= -1;
}
```

See the example:

```js
var speed = 3;
var ball = {
  x: 100,
  y: 200,
  radius: 50,

  draw: function() {
      fill('red');
      circle(this.x, this.y, this.radius*2);
  },
  move: function(){
      if (this.x > width-this.radius || this.x < this.radius) {
          speed *= -1;
      }
      this.x = this.x + speed;
  }
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500);
    background(200, 225, 200);
}

function draw() {
    background(200,225,200);
    ball.draw();
    ball.move();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```