# How do i invert my slider value in the code

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to multiply my slider value by minus one to make the ball come back and not leave the canvas. (I am using p5js)

```js
var x = 200;
var y = 200;
let speedcontrolx;
let speedcontroly;
let outputx;
let outputy;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  speedcontrolx = createSlider(-10, 10, 0);
  speedcontroly = createSlider(-10, 10, 0);
  outofboundsx = false;
  outofboundsy = false;
}

function draw() {
  outputx = speedcontrolx.value();
  outputy = speedcontroly.value();
  background("#dddddd");
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(4);
  noFill();
  ellipse(x, y, 40);
  x += outputx;
  y += outputy;

  if( x > width-24 || x < 0+24) {
    outputx = outputx *-1
  }

  if(y > height-24 || y < 0+24) {
    outputy = outputy *-1
   }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.7.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

the ball just leaves the canvas.

Comment: i forgot to delete the outofboundsx and y variables, because I tried to set flags but it didn't work.

Comment: You can [edit] your post.

Comment: You'll need to add `directionX = 1` and `directionY = 1` (or `velocityX`, `velocityY`) variables to keep track of the direction. When the ball hits the wall, reverse the direction to -1 on the respective axis, and position the ball outside the wall to resolve the collision on the next frame. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73655603/6243352)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59646152/6243352) shows how to do the bounce in 1 dimension, if the above example is too complex. Once you've understood the 1-d version, scale up to both axes.

Comment: If you got your answer, may you close by selecting the one answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```js
let x = 200;
let y = 200;
let speedXSlider, speedYSlider;
let speedX, speedY;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);

  // Use p5.js createSlider to create sliders
  speedXSlider = createSlider(-10, 10, 0);
  speedYSlider = createSlider(-10, 10, 0);
}

function draw() {
  background("#dddddd");
  
  // Get slider values
  speedX = speedXSlider.value();
  speedY = speedYSlider.value();

  // Update ball position
  x += speedX;
  y += speedY;
  
  // Check boundaries and invert direction if necessary
  if (x > width - 20 || x < 20) {
    speedX *= -1;
  }

  if (y > height - 20 || y < 20) {
    speedY *= -1;
  }

  // new Updated part
  // Adjust position to stay within canvas bounds
  x = constrain(x, 20, width - 20);
  y = constrain(y, 20, height - 20);

  // Draw the ball
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(4);
  noFill();
  ellipse(x, y, 40);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.7.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

- Don't use var, use let for variable declaration.
- I removed unnecessary checks.

You can try this code and let me know the result.

Comment: first of all, thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work either, now the ball just goes beyond the canvas and doesn't come back :C

Comment: please check my updated code.
constrain() is the function of p5.js

Comment: sorry for not answering, your code works in the sense of the ball staying in the window boundaries but I want the ball to reverse the speed, if it hits the boundaries so it looks like its bouncing off the edges

Comment: This might be a good article to read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript/Bounce_off_the_walls

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = 200;
var y = 200;
let speedcontrolx;
let speedcontroly;
let outputx = 1;
let outputy = 1;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  speedcontrolx = createSlider(-10, 10, 0);
  speedcontroly = createSlider(-10, 10, 0);
  outofboundsx = false;
  outofboundsy = false;
}

function draw() {
  background("#dddddd");
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(4);
  noFill();
  ellipse(x, y, 40);
  x += speedcontrolx.value() * outputx;
  y += speedcontroly.value() * outputy;

  if( x > width-24 || x < 0+24) {
    outputx *= -1
  }

  if(y > height-24 || y < 0+24) {
    outputy *= -1
   }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.7.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```